# DropdownList populated by DataSource, add one extra field?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, datasource

I have a dropdown list which I populated using a data source (in this case they are hotel names). I want to have one extra field in the list which says "Select a Hotel" which is the default selection when the user opens the page. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using c# or vb.net, Winforms, WPF or ASPX?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text "Select a Hotel" to be part of your results, then you will have to make it part of your query. Use an union, since you don't mention the type of DB you are using, I'm going to give you an example from MySQL.

```
select "Select a Hotel"
union
select hotelname from MyDB.hotels;
```

on the other hand, if you read the hotel names to a storage array, then you could add "Select a Hotel" to the array after reading from the DB.

Also another alternative, when you create the HTML you could add the "Select a Hotel" as part of the first option and then loop through the returned values from the DB. (This is pseudo code)

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Select a Hotel</option>
  // loop through storage array
  for (int i=0; i<hotels.size(); i++) {
    <option value="hotels[i].value">hotels[i].name</option>
  } //end loop
</select>
```

You've got three options here, hope one of these helps.